# asp.net c# validation on tab change event

Tags: c#, asp.net, tabcontrol, webforms

I'm creating a registration web form in asp.net with c# and framework 4.0.
I create a web page with a tab control (3 tab created using menu, multiview and 3 single view).
I would like to put a webusercontrol into the 3 view.

**The problem:**

In tab 1 I have a registration form with some mandatory fields. I would like to check if this fields are filled when I change switch from tab1 to tab2.

I would like to remain to the first tab until all the mandatory field are filled.

Answer (score 1):

Use Validation Groups and set one for each tab and then on client side tab changed event validate current group with :

```
Page_ClientValidate("GroupName")
```

more about this feature at :

http://www.dotnet-guide.com/validationgroups.html

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2004/10/24/246945.aspx